# Odoo16 - Owl farmework - Error when using userService("orm")

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

Error when using userService("orm") - odoo16
I was on a mission to create a new page, and here's how I did it.

1. root/controller => Create a Controller that renders the root template
   [image]
2. views/template.xml => Create a template containing a div with id root_owl
   [image]
3. static/src/js => Generate js to use owl framework
   [image]
4. static/src/xml => Create component to mount to root
   [image]
5. in file **manifest**
   [image]

and I get an error in step 3 with the message "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'orm' in undefined"

So how do I fix this error, thank you everyone

Comment: Could you provide the whole Traceback please ?

Comment: Odoo-16 provides already  tracking features... what is your purpose with your own coding ?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten semi-columns (`;`) at the line-end at 6 places in your js script... which surely mess up its interpretation:

```js
import {useState,Component,whenReady, App, onWillStart, mount} from "@odoo/owl";
//...
import {templates} from "@web/core/assets";
//...
this.orm = useService("orm");
//...
TrackingOwl.template = "tpc_custom_website.tracking_owl";
//...
const tracking_owl_root = document.querySelector("#root_owl");
//...
await mount(TrackingOwl, tracking_owl_root,{templates});
```

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please provide the content of your browser>inspect>console log  ...and the whole Server Traceback

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo, backend assets are typically handled by the **web.assets_backend** bundle. To add assets to the backend, use the **web.assets_backend**.

For more refer how **configurator.js** is used inside the module website.